# Template Specialization for a function without Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I need to specialize a function template in c++.

```
template<typename T>  
void doStuff<T>() {}
```

To

```
template<>
void doStuff<DefinedClass>();
```

and

```
template<>
void doStuff<DefinedClass2>();
```

I guess that is not the correct syntax (since it is not compiling). How should I do it?
Also, Since I will have not undefined template parameters in `doStuff<DefinedClass>`, would it be possible to declare the body in a .cpp?

Note: doStuff will use T wihtin its body to declare a variable.

Comment: When you say "it is not compiling", you should include the relevant error message.

Comment: Does `template<typename T> void doStuff<T>() {}` even compile in the first place (I think this `<T>` is invalid).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The primary template doesn't get a second pair of template arguments. Just this:

```
template <typename T> void doStuff() {}
//                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Only the specializations have both a `template <>` at the front and a `<...>` after the name, e.g.:

```
template <> void doStuff<int>() { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. If I write the specialization like: "template<> void <int>doStuff();"  I got: "invalid explicit specialization before '>' token"

Comment: If I put" template<typedef T>" I get "template-id `buildBom<int>' in declaration of primary template"

Comment: No, it should be `template<> void doStuff<int>();` for specialization and `template<typename T> void doStuff();` for general case...

Comment: @Synxis: Thanks! I added that example, and I removed the `...` from the first set, because you can't partially specialize functions anyway. Sometimes a less general answer is more helpful :-)

Answer (score 9):

The correct syntax for the primary template is:

```
template <typename T>
void doStuff() {}
```

To define a specialisation, do this:

```
template <>
void doStuff<DefinedClass>() { /* function body here */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I guess that is not the correct syntax (since it is not compiling). How should I do it?
>   doStuff will use T wihtin its body to declare a variable.

```
template<typename T>  
void doStuff() 
{
  T t = T();   // declare a T type variable

}
```

> would it be possible to declare the body in a .cpp?

C++  only supports `inclusive mode` only, you can't compile separately then link later.

From comment, if you want to specialize for `int` type:

```
template<>
void doStuff<int>()
{
}
```

Comment: ***inclusive  mode***? What's that? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?